# Is is possible to hardcode Google API credentials into my Java application?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, credentials

In the [following documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials), there are named points 1-4 how to provide credentials to my application. All of them I dislike, because they are making my application environment dependent.

Is it possible to hardcode credentials into my application, like using some API key or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your environement variable your API KEY:

```
export GOOGLE_API_KEY="xxxx"
```

or the JSON containing your credentials:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/home/toto/tmp/project-name-123456789.json
```